# Не проходит deploy на DigitalOcean c помощью Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, digitalocean

Делаю по [этой](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) инструкции, но ничего не выходит.

Пишет ошибку

```
00:32 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01 NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
```

Помогите мне пожалуйста. Я в этом деле новичок.

Comment: У вас там как минимум банальная невнимательность: встречаются как `/home/demo/myproject`, так и `/home/demo/apps/myproject`. Если после этого ещё останутся проблемы, изолируйте, что останется, и уберите лишнее из вопроса. Сейчас там целая россыпь слабосвязанных вещей, из которых непонятно, с какой из них у вас беда.

Comment: @D-side исправил свою невнимательность в конфигах.
Но все равно ошибка лезет:
00:32 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01 NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

Comment: *изолируйте, что останется, и уберите лишнее из вопроса* [2]

Comment: Хорошо, это всё сообщение об ошибке, или там ещё что-нибудь есть?

Comment: весь лог грузить?

Comment: Не знаю. Но как минимум такое сообщение об ошибке обычно сопровождается стектрейсом. Если он первой строчкой указывает в ваш код, посмотрите туда. Сравните с вашим руководством.

Comment: ...и осознайте, насколько беспомощным вас это "руководство для новичков" оставляет перед лицом проблем :)

Comment: @D-side да это уж очень краткое руководство. Не поясняющие все делали.Но тут другая ошибка :

BrowserifyRails::BrowserifyError: Unable to run node_modules/.bin/browserify. Ensure you have installed it with npm.

Comment: хотя я ставил browserify. 
demo@test8CPU$ browserify --version
14.3.0

Comment: @D-side Вы представляете мучаюсь уже с этим неделю. Никогда бы не сказал что есть вот такая вот задача, с которой можно неделю ...

Comment: Ставить ставили, но **туда ли**? Выясните, по какому пути он пытается запустить (по логам), а по какому запускаете вы (`which browserify`).

Comment: @D-side да сравнил, действительно пути запуска различаются капистрано берет с локальной папки в проекте node_modules/.bin/browserify, а установлена версия в системе /home/demo/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/browserify

Comment: @D-side а как теперь указать пути?

Comment: Видимо, вы не устанавливали зависимости для NodeJS (через NPM или Yarn, что там у вас), или Browserify нет в зависимостях. Это уже вам лучше знать.

Comment: NodeJS ставил через NPM по вот этому туториалу
[ссылка](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/node-js-ubuntu-16-04-ru)

Comment: Я не про NodeJS.

Comment: Вот эта же статья на русском. [Как развернуть Rails-приложение на DigitalOcean сервере с помощью Capistrano](https://medium.com/@alexandr52281/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-rails-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-digitalocean-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-capistrano-231bb6c03939)